# Data Factory / Data Flow - conditional split based on a number of records

Tags: azure-data-factory

I need to split a huge dataset into multiple files and each file must not have more than 100 000 rows.
I don't know if this is possible with Data Flow and the conditional split?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want simply split by a fixed number of rows, I've created a simple test.

1. Declare a parameter inside the dataflow to store the row count of your source dataset. If your source dataset is Azure sql, you can use Lookup activity to get the max Row_No. If your source dataset is Azure storage, you can use Azure Function activity to get the max Row_No. Then pass the value to the parameter.
   [image]
2. Here for test, set a static default value.
   [image]
3. Then we can set Number of partitions expression `$RowCount/10`, if you want 10 lines per file.
   [image]
4. We can set file names after division here.
   [image]
5. My source dataset contains 50 lines, so ADF will split it to 5 files. Judging by the Id column, it has randomly taken 10 rows of data.
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with 2 dataflows. 1 to get the row count and another to partition. This can also be achieved in 1 dataflow using a cache sink in the future.

Comment: I have tried several different types of solution to achieve what OP has asked also, because I also have the same problem. How would you do using only 1 dataflow? Because mine is not working.